# Variable not echoing with ' or " or \"

Tags: php, escaping

Having a little trouble with line 1 echoing the contents of the food item brand...

```
echo $hint='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.itemDetailTitle4.value=\"$brand\"; document.contactForm.itemDetailBrand4.value=4;">fill form</a>'.

$brand= $w->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

*update*

```
      $hint='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.musicDetailTitle4.value="'.$artist.'"; document.contactForm.musicDetailArtist4.value=4;">fill form'.$artist."-".$title."-".$id."</a>";
```

Comment: Sidenote: You do realize that your *posted* code is missing a *closing* semi-colon. Your dot at the end should have been a semi-colon, unless you've got more following that and concatenating the parts you've left out.

Comment: First, you need to add semicolon at the end of you echoing line. Second, is there any error message outputing for you?

Comment: Are you attempting to echo the value of $brand before it is set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's happening because variables are not parsed in single quotes:

```
..."javascript:document.contactForm.itemDetailTitle4.value="'. $brand .'"; document...
```

use concatenation instead, like above.

Comment: The output i now have is...  `code`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.itemDetailTitle4.value=" tomato="" soup";="" document.contactform.itemDetailTitle4.value="4;&quot;">fill form</a>`code`

Comment: you miss matched some quotes there. post your code, I can't fix it from the output.

Comment: escape your double quotes in there like so `value=\"'.$artist.'\"`

Answer (score 0):

Variables are only parsed between citation marks

```
echo 'Text $var'; //apostrophe will not parse variable
echo "Text $var"; //citation marks will parse
```

in your case you should do this so you do not have to fight with it:

```
echo $hint='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.itemDetailTitle4.value="' . $brand . '"; document.contactForm.itemDetailBrand4.value=4;">fill form</a>'.
```

Answer (score -1):

1. First
   `$brand= $w->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;`
2. Second

   `echo $hint='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.contactForm.itemDetailTitle4.value="'.$brand.'"; document.contactForm.itemDetailBrand4.value=4;">fill form</a>'`